# passing object to the struts action in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, struts2

I want to pass java.util.Date object to the struts action from unit test.

```java
Format frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
Date objStartDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
request.setParameter("startDate", frmt.format(objStartDate));
```

i also create new setter method in java class,

```java
public void setStartDate(String startDate) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
    this.startDate = df.parse(startDate);
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.
So How should i pass the object through unit test?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: If it's a *unit* test why are you simulating a request? A unit test should be testing the action in isolation, and setting the date on the action itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Request reference like below.

```
    action.servletRequest = new HttpServletRequestSimulator(null);
```

where `action` is reference of your Action class.

I think this will solve your problem.